# 'We're the best there is at what we do.' Structure is correct?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

While I instinctively know that the slogan is right, I'm not sure how to explain to folks who keep insisting there should be a comma after is. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see both points of view. Either you can see the underlying structure as

'We're the best there is' or you can see it as  'We're the best at what we do.'

A. In the first case we have 'We're the the best there is (at what we do).'

B. In the second case it's not so easily divisible. Maybe adding an extra 'that' helps, so

'We're the best (that there is) at what we do.'

My instinct is that your colleagues are reading it as in A and are seeing the final clause as parenthetical.

Personally I'm happy with your original version. It allows readers to make their own choice - or none.